# How to speed up building on framework-res module

Tags: android, compilation

I am working on project to modify some resouce file in framework. But i got a poor computer with just 2gb ram and not a very fast cpu. So everytime i compile this module i have to wait for about 40 seconds. I thought if i delete some picture files in res which i don't use in my device will speed up a little. Does anybody got a better idea?

Answer (score 0):

GNU make can handle parallel tasks with a -jN argument. Does your computer have a processor with multiple cores? If so, try to make with -jN argument, it's common to use a number of tasks N that's between 1 and 2 times the number of hardware threads on the computer being used for the build.
E.g.

```
$ make -j8
```

Comment: My cpu only have two cores. So even if i use make -j2 to compile, it also won't change much. But after i set the ccache option and remove some hdpi and ldpi resources, it compiled mush faster.